# Utility function for large number of agents.

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to write a utility function and stuck big time currently I have 1 member each of 2 classes. Given the scenario the utility function I have is

$\int_{a_D}\int_{a_O} \pi_{D}(a_D)\pi_O(a_O) r da_Dda_O$

where $\pi_D$ is the probability density function for the member of class D. Now the problem I am facing is that instead 1 member in each class. I have $m$ and $n$
members respectively and now I am struggling to write the utility function.